# In angular service call not getting value at first time issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[Here Demo Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezoltjppyZpnlM1cFN2Z?p=preview)

`Here` I attached the sample program for service call. In that Am facing the problem first time not getting the value properly.

1st time invocation:

---

[image]

2nd or more invocation:

---

[image]

May I know what was the problem? and help me to fix.
And why count executed first and datalength executed second?

Comment: `$http.get` makes an asynchronous call which will not be finished when you first use the result, hence the object will not be filled correctly.

Comment: use defer for your factory this might be resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

`$http.get` is calling async by default. We have to use promise to make it sync. Use this updated code refer to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/odKd9nyDQeh9NtrJF7dP?p=preview):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$filter', 'sampleService', '$http', function ($scope, $location, $filter, sampleService, $http) {
    $scope.getCount = function () {
        sampleService.getFile().then(function (data) {
            var dt = data.PRTGetSlotsBySessionResult;
            var count = $filter('filter')(dt, { "N": null });
            alert(JSON.stringify(count.length));
        });
    }
}]);

app.factory('sampleService', ['$http', '$filter', '$q', function ($http, $filter, $q) {

    return {
        object: '',
        makeRequest: function (url) {
            // Create the deffered object
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(url).then(function (resp) {
                deferred.resolve(resp.data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        getFile: function () {
            if (!this.object) {
                this.object = this.makeRequest("file.json");
            }
            // Return the myObject stored on the service
            return this.object;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: data.datalength = 0; this will throws an error because u defined only data it doesn't know what is data.datalength  and your trying assign 0 to it

Comment: can u provide that plunker with your suggested code......for me i am getting reference error in my console

Comment: i am still getting the following error with your plunker link also ReferenceError: datalength is not defined
    at Object.data.GetSlotData (script.js:23)

Comment: okay now i am getting alert from the second click onwards.....fir the first time its undef

Comment: I am also having same issue, any one can resolve the issue ?

Comment: @Vispan , okay now i am getting values from the second click onwards.....for the first time count is 0

Comment: @Nelson have you checked plunker. its working smooth with the first click onwards